# How to uninstall Ubuntu from one drive and install in another drive?

Tags: partitioning, uninstall, system-installation

I've recently installed Ubuntu 13.04. On the installation process I've select "Install Ubuntu Alongside Windows 7" or the option similar of that. So I didn't know in which drive Ubuntu is installed (Windows 7 is in drive C). I didn't find out any option on Control Panel (in Windows 7) to remove Ubuntu. Can anyone tell me how to remove Ubuntu so that I can install it in my desire drive?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since you've used the *"[Install alongside Windows](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GraphicalInstall#continueinstall)"* option, you've allowed automatic partition resizing where the Windows partition would be shrunk by the amount that you selected for Ubuntu, and appropriate partition will be created to get Ubuntu installed there.

You can then restart and choose the OS you want to boot from the GRUB menu.

---

#### *"... how to uninstall Ubuntu from one drive and install in another drive?"*

Here are the points you'll have to remember while you do this:

1. Boot Live Ubuntu and with the help of *partition manager* delete the partition where Ubuntu is currently installed, and this will create some ***unallocated space***;
2. Using partition manager, you'll have to assign a proper *filesystem* to the unallocated space i.e. create a new partition; and maybe you'd look to ***merge*** it to some other partition;
3. You can then appropriately format (with ***ext**** filesystem) the target drive/partition where you want to install Ubuntu and install there. (You can install Ubuntu to extended partitions; while **root** (i.e. `/`) partition is a must, you can also create **swap** partition or separate partitions for your `/home`, `/boot` if you prefer to.)

---

References:

- [Installing Ubuntu to a Specific Partition ("Something Else")](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Installing_Ubuntu_to_a_Specific_Partition_.28.22Something_Else.22.29:)
- [(Step 7-C "Something Else.."): Step-by-step beginner's guide to installing Ubuntu](http://www.techspot.com/community/topics/step-by-step-beginners-guide-to-installing-ubuntu-11-10.172128/)

Answer (score 0):

First, what you are calling "drives" are actually partitions.
Boot your live DVD or usb
Start the installation program.
Choose "Something Else"
You will be able to see the partitions listed, and you will see which one is your Ubuntu partition.
Install Ubuntu to that partition - you do not have to worry about deleting the previous Ubuntu.
If you want to install Ubuntu to a different partition, you can create that partition with the Windows partition manager, or with the gparted program on the live DVD before you begin the installation program.
[How to use manual partitioning during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation)
http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/gparted.html#mozTocId17965

Comment: I can do it. But I want to remove Ubuntu before new installation. Is there any way to remove Ubuntu?